# Device ID & Platform Not Retrieving Amazon Fire OS

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

Is there any issue when trying to retrieve the device ID or platform from a Amazon fire OS device? it's working fine for iOS and Android but does not get anything when testing on a Amazon device.

I am using http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/device/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cordova Device plugin doesn't support getting UUID nor platform from an Amazon Fire OS device. According to [this page](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_device_device.md.html) these are supported platforms:

- Android
- BlackBerry 10
- iOS
- Tizen
- Windows Phone 7 and 8
- Windows 8